# Using MVVM with CollectionViewSource

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm, collectionviewsource

I'm trying to use CollectionViewSource to display some data, and all the examples/tutorials I've seen have a custom class built, which they use in another class, which inherits from ObservableCollection.  I'm new to both using CollectionViewSource and this is only my third implementation of MVVM, so I might misunderstand the programming pattern, but my question is: 
where do I put the ObservableCollection class and/or custom class?

I feel like they should go in the Model, but then I'm not sure what gets bound to the View.  Do I just build these as external classes, and then reference them in Model/ViewModel?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, I would say that there is no need to inherit from `ObservableCollection<T>` unless you are adding functionality to it which I have rarely, if ever, actually needed to do.

In most cases I create ViewModel properties of type `ObservableCollection<T>` and then populate them from the Model whenever I load the data.  This has the advantage that the Model does not need to use `ObservableCollection<T>` (it can be any `IEnumerable<T>`) and it means that later when I (almost inevitably) want to wrap whatever I'm getting back from the Model in *another* instance-specific view model I am only obliged to change my existing view model classes.

Once you have a property on your view model you can simply bind your `CollectionViewSource` to that property and it will do everything from there.  It's worth noting that the `CollectionViewSource` doesn't actually care about the type of the property, so you can expose your collection to the View as an `ICollection<T>`, `IEnumerable<T>` or (I believe) even as an `object` and the `CollectionViewSource` will still treat it the same as if it is exposed as an `ObservableCollection<T>`.

Sorry for the slightly rambling answer.  The concise version would be "it depends on the situation" but I tend to follow this general approach in most cases.